# Emscripten - How to override locateFile when compiled with MODULARIZE options

Tags: emscripten

I have some files added to the virtual file system using --preload-file

I try to change the data file location using:

```
MyModule['locateFile'] = function(path, prefix) {
  if (path.endsWith(".data")) return "resources/" + path
  return prefix + path
}
```

But if I add `-s MODULARIZE=1 -s 'EXPORT_NAME="MyModule"'`, it doesn't work.

I try to add the locateFile function in a dedicated script as explained [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/packaging_files.html#changing-the-data-file-location).

I also tried using `pre-js` and `extern-pre-js` options but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution by reading the [FAQ](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions) and the [settings.js](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/src/settings.js) file, in particular:

> The factory function accepts 1 parameter, an object with default
> values for the module instance:
>
> const module = await EXPORT_NAME({ option: value, ... });

So we can pass the function like this:

```
function locateFile(path, prefix) {
  if (path.endsWith(".data")) return "resources/" + path
  return prefix + path
}

MyModule({'locateFile' : locateFile}).then(...)
```